# Throw Exceptions with custom stack trace

Tags: .net, language-agnostic, exception

Is it possible to throw an exception (could be any exception) with a customized stack trace?

As a concrete example: lets say I have a set of some small static utility methods which might throw exceptions. However I would like the exception to appear to have originated from the previous method instead of the utility method (I want to ignore the 1st frame of the trace).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Messing around with the stack trace really doesn't sound like a good idea, even if it is possible (I'm doubtful of that). Tell me, why would you want to do that anyway? The .NET framework itself (the BCL) often uses static utility methods to throw exceptions, in the way that you suggest (`ThrowHelper` is its name in at least some parts of the framework), and it certainly does hide anything in the stack trace.

Here's an example stack trace from a test I just ran:

```
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at HelloWorld.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\...\Program.cs:line 23
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

As you can see, the BCL uses the `ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException` method, and it's clearly visible in the stack trace. If you want to mark the helper method with the `DebuggerNonUserCode` attribute, then that would seem fair enough to me (though it's not done in the BCL).

Comment: I suppose you're right actually. The main reason I wanted to do this was to "pretty up" debugging these exceptions when thrown. However I think the better way to accomplish what I want is to use the [DebuggerNonUserCode] attribute on my methods.

Comment: Yeah, I see exactly where you're coming from. The .NET helper methods don't use the DebuggerNonUserCode attribute, but it sounds like a sensible idea to me.

Answer (score 12):

The StackTrace property is virtual - create your own derived Exception class and have the property return whatever you want.

Comment: I would do this except I'd prefer to throw the original Exception type. And I don't want to pass it around as an inner exception.

Comment: You can have your own exception inherit from many (maybe all) of the normal exceptions, so your custom exception, with a custom StackTrace, could be caught by a catch block for a standard exception.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work very well, is because the base ToString implementation on Exception doesn't use the StackTrace property, it calls the GetStackTrace private method (which is what the StackTrace property calls), so this means that your override is useless in regards to the default behavior. A very unfortunate design decision that I'm sure they cannot possibly change at this point.